# Different ways of making changes existing website

Tags: php, mysql, web-deployment

I have an admin page that I want to make some changes. The website has been built using php and mysql, by someone else and it is up running.

First thing came to my mind was:

1. Download source code and make a local copy of everything and work on that and once finished upload to hosting again.(using Xampp)
2. I also have been advised to make another copy of server and make changes on the server instead of running it locally.

**My question is:** *Second option seems much easier , but does that mean in order to test every little detail I have to save file, upload back to server and run it?*

Am i missing something?

Comment: I'd highly suggest researching version control.

Comment: If you don't upload it to the server, how will you run it?

Comment: Yes - you would. Its far more reasonable to have a local copy and use FTP or VCS or whatever to deploy your finished code.

Comment: I see. The reason I wanted the second option because, I could not run it locally, probably needs some changes in order to adapt the local environment.(database connection etc). What do you think about make changes on the hosting editor?

Comment: Hosting editor? What is that? For a local development environment and a prod environment you can declare a constant and set it to a value to determine rather to use a specific database etc...

Comment: The website is hosted on bluehost and it has built in editor than you can use. Probably not the most efficient way of making changes.